# Jekyll variables inside for loops to _data

Tags: html, for-loop, zurb-foundation, jekyll

So I want to implement a for loop in Jekyll with a variable to the _data file, kinda like

```
{% for person in site.data.{{ page.base }}.persons %}
{{ person.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

In this case `{{ page.base }}` is set to `build`, I also need it to be set to `program`, `manage`, and `web`. And all these variables are defined in my `build.md` or `program.md` and so on.

I have my for loop in the `_layouts` folder. I've tried using the `[page.base]` method but it's not working. Here is my code:

```
---
layout: default
---
<div class="column-wrapper">
    <div class="grid-x">
        <div class="large-6 shrink cell">
            <header class="post-header">
                <h1 class="post-title">{{ page.title | escape }}</h1>
                <div class="no-image-column-wrapper">
                    <p class="indent">{{ page.description }}</p>
                </div>
            </header>
        </div>
        <div class="large-6 shrink cell">
            {% include slideshow.html %}
        </div>
        {% for person in site.data.build.persons %}
        <div class="large-6 shrink cell">
            <div class="team-image">
                <img src="/images/{{ page.base }}/{{ person.name }}.jpg">
            </div>
            <style type="text/css">

                .team-image {

                    margin-bottom: 4.5rem;
                    margin-top: 2rem;
                    max-height: 1rem;
                    max-width: 16rem;
                    margin-right: 10rem;
                    margin-left: 10rem;
                    padding-bottom: 5rem;

                }

            </style>
        </div>
        <div class="large-6 shrink cell">
            <div class="no-image-column-wrapper">
                <div class="team-bio">
                    <h3>{{ person.name }}</h3>
                    <br>
                    <p>What grade are you in? <strong>{{ person.grade }}</strong></p>
                    <p>What is your role in robotics? <strong>{{ person.role }}</strong></p>
                    <p>What is your favorite ice cream? <strong>{{ person.fav }}</strong></p>
                    <p>What would you like to major in? <strong>{{ person.major }}</strong></p>
                    <p>What is your biggest pet peeve? <strong>{{ person.pp }}</strong></p>
                    <p>What is your spirit animal? <strong>{{ person.sa }}</strong></p>
                    <p>Why are you intrested in robotics? <strong>{{ person.intrest }}</strong></p>

                    <style type="text/css">

                    .team-bio {

                        padding-bottom: 5rem;

                    }


                    </style>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my `build.md` YAML, (I think it's YAML).

```
---
title: Build Team
layout: team
permalink: /teams/build/
base: build
path: images/build/pic
description: The build team is dedicated to building the robot.
---
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be simpler. This could be your persons.yml:

```
- name: Tom
  teams:
    - build
    - program
- name: Violet
  teams:
    - program
```

This could be your Liquid:

```
{% for person in site.data.persons %}
  {% if person.teams contains page.base %}
    {{ person.name }}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```